# GlusterFS - Unable to list files within a specific directory on a Gluster fuse mount point

Tags: linux, mount, fuse, volume, glusterfs

We have a single volume 'gvol0' which is split across two nodes (replicated), server1 and server2:

Here is the sanitised volume info:

```
Volume Name: gvol0
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 434237432743274327473247
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: server1:/var/lib/gvol0/brick1
Brick2: server2:/var/lib/gvol0/brick2
Options Reconfigured:
nfs.rpc-auth-allow: x.x.x.*
nfs.export-volumes: on
nfs.addr-namelookup: off
auth.allow: x.x.x.*
transport.address-family: inet
performance.readdir-ahead: on
nfs.disable: off
```

Each brick is then mounted on the server at the following mount point location: /mnt/gluster/gvol0/

**The issue we are facing is as follows:**

On server1, there is a particular folder on the mount point, let's call it "_data" that doesn't display any subfolder, nor files within it. It is however possible to stat these files/folders and even edit files and successfully write to the disk:

```
File: ‘_data’
Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 131072 directory
Device: 27h/39d Inode: 10981725783047031592  Links: 35
Access: (2775/drwxrwsr-x)  Uid: (   48/  apache)   Gid: ( 
1024/teamgroup)
Context: system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0
Access: 2017-06-13 15:42:18.653306032 +0000
Modify: 2017-06-13 15:42:22.461305492 +0000
Change: 2017-06-13 15:42:22.461305492 +0000
Birth: -
```

The weird thing is, that this problem doesn't exist on the mount point on server2 AND I am able to successfully list folders and files within _data on the brick itself at /var/lib/gvol0/brick1/_data/

All volumes are running, including the self-healing daemons:

```
Status of volume: gvol0
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick server1:/var/lib/gvol0/brick1         49156     0          Y       997
Brick server2:/var/lib/gvol0/brick2         49154     0          Y       1109
NFS Server on localhost                     2049      0          Y       17085
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       17093
NFS Server on server 1                      2049      0          Y       4971
Self-heal Daemon on server 2                N/A       N/A        Y       4979

Task Status of Volume gvol0
```

Running the self heal command doesn't return any issues:

```
Brick server1:/var/lib/gvol0/brick1
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0

Brick server2:/var/lib/gvol0/brick2
Status: Connected
Number of entries: 0
```

Has anyone experienced this before and could you give me anything else to look into? I can't see anything obvious in the log files within /var/log/glusterfs/...

Thanks!

Comment: Managed to get the _data folder to appear as normal, after moving/renaming the folder within terminal. Can anyone explain a possible cause for this, I'm keen to avoid any reoccurrence!

Comment: Any chance you (or anyone else running into this) figured out a cause or a general fix for this? I'm seeing what seems to be the exact same issue, but have no clue where to look.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, but just to let everyone know that the response I got on Gluster's bugzilla response was that the version I was on was unsupported and that I should upgrade (3.x). I've upgraded to version 4.0 and haven't seen a reoccurrence so far.